# FLUTTER: Unhandled Exception: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, error-handling, stream-builder

I have a problem with this exception and I am stuck, I need your help. I use navigator inside of a streambuilder, I already use it inside of streambuilder but this time I have an exception and I don't know how to solve it. It try to add dispose function but I don't know how to close a streambuilder.

this is my state `Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    changestate();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            Text('VOUS', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50)),
            Text(
              'devez ' + legage,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30),
            Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/hands/2htop.png')),
            SizedBox(height: 30),
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: Firestore.instance
                    .collection('rooms')
                    .document(pincode)
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData &&
                      snapshot.data['nb screen'] == 1) {
                    gotdata++;
                    newduel(context);
                  }
                  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: Firestore.instance
                        .collection('rooms')
                        .document(pincode)
                        .collection('users')
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData)
                        return Text("Chargement....");
                      else {
                        return new GridView.count(
                            crossAxisCount: 5,
                            children: snapshot.data.documents
                                .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                              return Container(
                                child: OvalPic(
                                    document['photo'], document['couleur']),
                              );
                            }).toList());
                      }
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                child: (ffull2 == 0)
                    ? AnimatedLiquidLinearProgressIndicator()
                    : fgbutton(mypink, 'DUEL SUIVANT', context)),
            SizedBox(height: 30)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }`

```
void changestate() {
if (dejareload == 0) {
  dejareload++;
  Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      () => setState(() {
            ffull2 = 1;
          }));
}
```

}

and this is what is in newduel:

`Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Votes()));`

ERROR IS:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your setState method with a mounted condition like below.

the problem is, I think you made an API call somewhere then you dispose the page and the data arrives at the page when its already disposed, or any delayed actions.

```
void changestate() {
if (dejareload == 0) {
  dejareload++;
   if(mounted){
      Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      () => setState(() {
            ffull2 = 1;
      }));
   }

}
```

Comment: It didn't works :/ I edit my post to add debug error